# Need help with incrementing 2 variables in post form

Tags: php, mysql, forms, input

I'm trying to allow a user to edit a row of their data with POST from a displayed form.  The query is working and the table properly displays everything except a name value in the form input field.  I've tried numerous variations but the name value keeps coming up blank. The problem might be with this line:

```
       echo $field_name;
```

Here is the code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">

<?

$qry = "SELECT activity, site, date, FROM home WHERE user_id='$session->user_id' ORDER BY date";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$field_name = mysql_field_name($res, 0);

function mysql_fetch_all($res) {

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $return[] = $row;
    }

   return $return;
}

function create_table($dataArr) {
    echo "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"POST\"><table><tr>";
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"";
        echo $field_name;
        echo "\" maxlength=\"30\" value=" .$dataArr[$j]. "></td>";
    }
    echo "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"subedit\" value=\"1\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\"></td></tr></table></form>";
}

$all = mysql_fetch_all($res);

echo "<table class='data_table'>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><h2>Current Profile</h2></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><small><td>Activity&nbsp;</td><td>Site&nbsp;</td><td>Date&nbsp;</td></small></tr>";

for($i = 0; $i < count($all); $i++) {
    create_table($all[$i]);
}

echo "</table></form>";
```

Answer (score 0):

`$field_name` is out of scope (check out [PHP's variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) page).  Try changing your `create_table` function to accept the `$field_name` var like so:

```
function create_table($dataArr, $field_name) {
...
}
...
for($i = 0; $i < count($all); $i++) {
    create_table($all[$i], $field_name);
}
```

**Or** using global (not as recommended)

```
function create_table($dataArr) {
    global $field_name;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It works but I'm getting the 1st field repeating for each name-- that is, the first field "activity_name" is showing up in each name="", not counting up the way the $dataArr value does in the value="" fields.  Do I need to do more than insert the incrementing variable like this:          {echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"$field_name[$j]\" maxlength=\"30\" value=\"$dataArr[$j]\"></td>";}  It strikes me that what I'm trying to do must be a very common procedure (ie. serve up user info in a table, allow user to edit a row in that table and update database using post) b

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">

<?

$qry = "SELECT activity, site, date, FROM home WHERE user_id='$session->user_id' ORDER BY date";
$res = mysql_query($qry);
$field_name = mysql_field_name($res, 0);

function mysql_fetch_all($res) {

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $return[] = $row;
    }

   return $return;
}

function create_table($dataArr, $field_name) {
    echo "<form action=\"process.php\" method=\"POST\"><table><tr>";
    for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"";
        echo $field_name;
        echo "\" maxlength=\"30\" value=" .$dataArr[$j]. "></td>";
    }
    echo "<td><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"subedit\" value=\"1\"><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Update\"></td></tr></table></form>";
}

$all = mysql_fetch_all($res);

echo "<table class='data_table'>";
echo "<tr><td colspan=\"3\"><h2>Current Profile</h2></td></tr>";
echo "<tr><small><td>Activity&nbsp;</td><td>Site&nbsp;</td><td>Date&nbsp;</td></small></tr>";

for($i = 0; $i < count($all); $i++) {
    create_table($all[$i], $field_name);
}

echo "</table></form>";
```

However, I do recommend that you try to create a Table class.  It would be much more efficient and neater.

Comment: Thanks but that's the code I've been using, it works for the $dataArr variable, each value incrementing so that the whole table displays nicely, but with the $field_name I either get a truncated 1st letter which repeats for each field of the row, then shows the next letter of the 1st field repeating all through the second row-- that's when the code is:         echo "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"";
        echo $field_name[$j];
        echo "\" maxlength=\"30\" value=" .$dataArr[$j]. "></td>";  or it shows the first field for every name= "activity_name" when the [$j] is not included as here:

Comment: Ok, I'm taking note of your Table Class recommendation.  Maybe the truncating issue has something to do with an included form.php file.  I'm looking at it.

Comment: Could you maybe take a screenshot of some of the MySQL data and then a screenshot of the HTML output to see what you mean by truncation issue?  Also, are you using the exact code I put or the code that is in your original question?